# Reading words from file stooring in 2D Array

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to work with "dynamic" arrays in C. I want this code to read

```
printer,kekroflmeow,augustus,rofl,mao,kek,burger,lol,zomg,apo,abe,ago,lorem,ipsum,solar,sit,whan,kong,ping,roflstomp,dennis,hotdog,ketchup,viva,north
```

And store it in a 2D array (dynamically, I want to be able to both add and remove words). The words can not be longer than 20 characters. I got it working mostly, I have two problems, char **str is from the main file were the variable is char *mWords[20], however that apperently means it can contain 20 words with an undefined length, which is the opposite of what I want.

You might also want the getWordsFroMFile (char **str) function.

```
// get words from file; delimiter , stores them in str[word][character]
int getWordsFromFile (char **str) {
    FILE *tFile;

    int file_size;
    char *file_ptr;

    // load the file and check if it exists
    tFile = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    if (tFile == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot open file '%s'", FILENAME);
        exit (1);
    }

    // get size of file in bytes (1 byte = 1 char)
    fseek (tFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell (tFile);

    // back to start of tFile
    rewind (tFile);

    // allocate memory
    file_ptr = (char*) malloc (file_size);
    if (file_ptr == NULL) {
        printf ("Could not read file '%s'", FILENAME);
        exit (2);
    }

    // file -> buffer
    int size = fread (file_ptr, 1, file_size, tFile);
    file_ptr[size] = '\0';
    fclose(tFile);

    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (file_ptr, ",");

    int tWords = 0;
    while (pch != NULL) {
        if (sizeof(pch) < MAX_WORD_LEN && pch != "") {

            // if word only contains valid characters A-Z and/or a-z
            if (isValidWord(pch)) {
                // good, remove trim word and place it in str[tWords]
                str[tWords++] = trimWord(pch);
            } else {
                printf ("Invalid word in '%s': '%s' contains illegal characters.\n", FILENAME, pch);
            }
        }
        pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }

    return tWords;
}
```

It is called from main.cpp as (MAX_WORD_LEN is 20)

```
char *mWords[MAX_WORD_LEN];
int mWordsCount = getWordsFromFile (mWords);
```

Updated the fread() to add a terminating \0

Thanks in advance,

Emz

Comment: Easy issue first: Unless you were thinking about something entirely else, `fread` *does* what you think it would do: read *n* bytes. But it does not know that *you* are going to treat that data as a C string, and so you have to add a terminating zero to your string.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. I guessed that was a problem, but instead of trying to solve it I was trying to figure out it something else was the problem. Thanks

Comment: `sizeof(pch)`  --> `strlen(pch)`, `pch != ""` --> ``*pch != '\0'``

Comment: `file_size = ftell (tFile);` May not be the correct file size.

Comment: You still need to *allocate* the extra zero byte. Also, when using `fread` you should use file open mode `"rb"` (for "binary") to avoid Carriage Return/Line Feed conversions.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, a char is 1 byte, so won't sizeof() and strlen() produce the same thing? Also the pch != "" to *pch != '\0' I don't see why I would need it either? I can not find any error with my code beside the array initialization being wrong.

Comment: It can be seen immediately if you try it. `sizeof(pch)` returns the size of the pointer.  It is not possible to examine the equivalence of the string using `!=`.

Comment: I haven't found any errors using r and sizeof, after some reading however I believe you are right. Both are changed. I am also fairly sure how I will allocate the data for multidimensional arrays. Making **words work fine. Thanks for all your help. I will update the code soon (tm) to reflect the changes made.